# Sturm-Liouville and Continuity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If you have a differential equation

$$ y'' + R(x)y' + (Q(x) + \lambda P(x))y = 0$$ on some interval $(a,b)$ why must the coefficient functions be continuous on this interval? My guess is that if you are trying to solve the equation for some $y(x)$ valid on $(a,b)$, you don't really want to be multiplying that solution by functions that aren't continuous since you want a valid solution $y(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

Next, if we multiply the above second order differential equation by the integrating factor 
$$ r(x) = e^{\int R(x)dx}$$

and use the product rule to simplify we get

$$(r(x)y')' + (q(x) + \lambda p(x)) = 0$$
where $q(x) = Q(x)e^{\int R(x)dx}$ and $p(x) = P(x)e^{\int R(x)dx}$. This is Sturm-Liouville form.

Why must $p, q, r,$ and $r'$ be continuous on $(a,b)$. My guess is the same the above response. My book also specifies that $r(x) > 0$ and $p(x) > 0$. Why are these conditions necessary? I'd guess that if $r=0$ then we lose the second order part of the differential equation. If $p = 0$ then we lose the $\lambda$ part of the equation. But why can't they be negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual theorems on existence and uniqueness of solutions for an equation
$$
y''=f(x,y,y')
$$
require $f$ to be continuous. When the equation is
$$
y'' = -R(x)y' - (Q(x) - \lambda P(x))y
$$
this means that you want $P$, $Q$ and $R$ continuous.

Also, in general you want your solution to be $C^2$, which means that the right hand side must be continuous.

Without the continuity condition, the definition of solution and the results of existence and uniqueness of solution are more complicated. Consider for instance the equation $y'=p(x)y$ where $p(x)=0$ if $x<0$, $p(x)=1$ if $x\ge0$. The solution is 
$$
y(x)=\begin{cases} C & x<0,\\ C\,e^x & x\ge0,\end{cases}
$$
which is not differentiable at $x=0$ unless $C=0$. So, in what sense does $y$ satisfy the equation at $x=0$?

Comment: $y$ would satisfy the above equation when $y = 0$, a trivial solution which usually isn't what we are looking for?

Comment: It was just an example of a first order equation (not like the Sturm-Liouville problem, which is second order) to show you the type of problems that may arise if you allow discontinuous right hand sides in the equation.